# Perfomance improvement rails postgreql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Rails `5.2`, Postgresql

```
class School < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :teacher_records
    has_many :teachers, through: :teacher_records
end
```

`TeacherRecord` model has #`teacher_id`, #`school_id`

```
class TeacherRecord < ApplicationRecord
end
```

`Teacher` model

```
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
 scope :search_by_full_name ->(query) { where("CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) LIKE ?", "%#{query}%") }
end
```

Recently we imported `150000000` records of teachers from various sources.

**Issue**:
Search by full name takes `40seconds` to return the results.

**Issue 2:**
Loading in table with pagination (10 records each page) takes 15 seconds for some small school which has few hundred records.

Comment: Please see options here: [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fix this issue by converting the database into `multi-tenant` schema.

New schema will be created for each school when signup.

[image]

There is a powerful gem [apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) to create a multi-tenant database